# How to do calculation in HTML table using JavaScript as I am making a dynamic invoice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the total amount computed after entering the quantity, cost and discount field.
Would using `onchange` work or what should I do?

```js
function calculatePrice(costElement,qtyElement, discElement, priceElement) {
        priceElement.value = qtyElement.value * costElement.value - ((discElement.value * qtyElement.value * costElement.value)/100);
}

function myfunction(){
   var table=document.getElementById("mytable");

   //adding row
   var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
   var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
   var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
   var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
   var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
   var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
   var cell6=row.insertCell(5);

   // addind rows and values
   var objInputCheckBox = document.createElement("input");
      objInputCheckBox.type = "checkbox";
      cell1.appendChild(objInputCheckBox);

      var ele2 = document.createElement('input');
                ele2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                ele2.setAttribute('value', '');
            cell2.appendChild(ele2);

            //cost
   var ele3 = document.createElement('input');
                ele3.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                ele3.setAttribute('value', '');
                ele3.onchange = function(){
          calculatePrice(this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[2].childNodes[0], this, this, this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[5].childNodes[0]);
    };
            cell3.appendChild(ele3);

   //qty
   var ele4 = document.createElement('input');
                ele4.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                ele4.setAttribute('value', '');
                ele4.onchange = function(){
            calculatePrice(this, this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[3].childNodes[0], this, this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[5].childNodes[0]);
    };
            cell4.appendChild(ele4);

            //discount
            var ele5 = document.createElement('input');
                ele5.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                ele5.setAttribute('value', '');
                ele5.onchange = function(){
            calculatePrice(this, this, this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[4].childNodes[0], this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[5].childNodes[0]);
    }; 
   cell5.appendChild(ele5);

   var ele6 =  document.createElement('input');
    ele6.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    ele6.setAttribute('value', '');
   cell6.appendChild(ele6);
}

function delrow(id){
 var table=document.getElementById(id);
 var rowcount=table.rows.length;

  for(var i=0;i<rowcount;i++){
   var row= table.rows[i];
   var chk=row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
   if(chk.checked){
    table.deleteRow(i);
    rowcount--;
    i--;
   }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Table</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/table.js"></script>
 <style>
 table, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="mytable">
  <tr>
   <th> </th>
   <th>Item</th>
   <th>Cost</th>
   <th>Quantity</th>
   <th>Discount</th>
   <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <button onclick="myfunction()">Add</button>
 <button  onclick="delrow('mytable')">Delete</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I have not done CSS styling to it properly as my focus is to calculate the total price.
I tried it doing many times and even searched up but couldn't get it.
Somewhere I saw:

```
this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[4].childNodes[0]
```

What does this means?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? And yes, listening to the `change` event on your input fields is one way of achieving what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges

function calculatePrice(costElement,qtyElement, discElement, priceElement) {
        priceElement.value = qtyElement.value * costElement.value - ((discElement.value * qtyElement.value * costElement.value)/100);
}

I made this function and pass values as

ele3.onchange = function(){       calculatePrice(this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[2].childNodes[0], this, this, this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[5].childNodes[0]);
    };

Like that for 3rd,4th,5th column.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges I tried doing this

Answer (score 2):

I would use `.onkeyup` for more responsive feedback, and then add a handler that is passed the row that you created like so:

```js
    function calculateCost(row) {
        return function () {
            row.total.value = row.cost.value * row.qty.value * row.discount.value
        }
    }

    function myfunction() {
        var table = document.getElementById("mytable");

        //adding row
        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);

        // addind rows and values
        var objInputCheckBox = document.createElement("input");
        objInputCheckBox.type = "checkbox";
        cell1.appendChild(objInputCheckBox);

        //item
        var ele2 = document.createElement('input');
        ele2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        ele2.setAttribute('value', '');
        cell2.appendChild(ele2);

        //cost
        var ele3 = document.createElement('input');
        ele3.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        ele3.setAttribute('value', '');

        cell3.appendChild(ele3);

        //qty
        var ele4 = document.createElement('input');
        ele4.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        ele4.setAttribute('value', '');

        cell4.appendChild(ele4);

        //discount
        var ele5 = document.createElement('input');
        ele5.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        ele5.setAttribute('value', '');

        cell5.appendChild(ele5);

        //total
        var ele6 = document.createElement('input');
        ele6.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        ele6.setAttribute('value', '');
        cell6.appendChild(ele6);
        var row = {
            item: ele2,
            cost: ele3,
            qty: ele4,
            discount: ele5,
            total: ele6
        }
        var updateCostHandler = calculateCost(row);
        row.cost.onkeyup = updateCostHandler;
        row.qty.onkeyup = updateCostHandler;
        row.discount.onkeyup = updateCostHandler;
    }


    function delrow(id) {
        var table = document.getElementById(id);
        var rowcount = table.rows.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chk = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if (chk.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowcount--;
                i--;
            }
        }

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Table</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/table.js"></script>
 <style>
 table, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="mytable">
  <tr>
   <th> </th>
   <th>Item</th>
   <th>Cost</th>
   <th>Quantity</th>
   <th>Discount</th>
   <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <button onclick="myfunction()">Add</button>
 <button  onclick="delrow('mytable')">Delete</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```